# PHP Force Apache error

Tags: php, apache

Thanks to this forum, I learnt PHP header function does not actually send header to Apache server but only to the client.

What I wanna do is to generate an error 500, and let Apache displays its corresponding page. Is there a way to force it ?

Thanks in advance !
(and allez les bleus !)

Comment: Hmm, don't know whether this is possible. What do you want to do  this for, and at which point do you want to generate the 500?

Comment: And who are those blue people you are referring to? Are they suffering from a lack of oxygen? ;)

Comment: actually, we made some Apache custom error pages, and I'm cleaning up the PHP error handling, in order to have a unique error page (which would be the Apache one)...
I'll try to write a bad .htaccess directive (or how to learn do something wrong on purpose...)

and about the bleus, I guess you'll hear more about it on 11th of July ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a redirect to a URL that causes a 500.

For example a url with an invalid .htaccess directive.

Comment: I tried to put in the .htaccess at the file
RewriteRule ^error\.php$ /force_error_500.php [NC,R=500]

(force_error_500.php does not exist)

header('Location:error.php'); causes only a 404... 
I guess I missed a point :(

Comment: Yes... create an INVALID .htaccess file. Yours was a valid one :)

Comment: sorry, sorry, sorry...
now I have this:
RewriteRule ^error\.php$ /stupid_directive.php [YMCA]

on every URL I go, I got a 500... but I'd like to get it only with www.mysite.com/error.php...

Comment: OK, create a directory and put the invaild htaccess in there. In error.php just redirect to that directory.

Answer (score 4):

There's a way of sending a 500 Error to the browser, but you'll have to provide the page yourself:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
echo <<<ERRORTEXT
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it 
from fulfilling the request.
ERRORTEXT;
// also notify server operator, maybe?
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a broken cgi script:

```
// Don't include stdio
int main() {
   printf("This won't work.\n");
   return 0;
}
```