# Is it possible to deliberately generate Error 500 with Charles proxy or any other tool without disturbing the server

Tags: http, drupal-7, charles-proxy

I am trying to generate error 500 for a drupal based website. I dont have the privileges to make any changes to the server. Is there a way to generate Error 500 - internal server error, without disturbing the server?

Comment: Trying to do this as well... I am setting a breakpoint on my response and trying to change 200 to 500 in Charles but no-go

Answer (score 1):

Try [Piskvor's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004407/php-force-apache-error). I'm not sure what would qualify "disturbing the server" but you may be able to try putting it in a module as a page callback, or in a node body with the PHP filter enabled. I haven't tested it, but that's where I'd start.

Code from the quoted post:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
echo <<<ERRORTEXT
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it 
from fulfilling the request.
ERRORTEXT;
// also notify server operator, maybe?
exit;
?>
```